# How to read JSON data instead of a line from socket?

Tags: java, android, json, sockets, tcp

My application connects to a sensor over WiFi direct. Then it connects to a socket and is supposed to read data. The data is JSON and looks like {"d":{temp_mC";33416,"humidity_ppm"...more data....}}. The sensor sends data every 2 minutes. Before I only have been able to read lines that are sent by a server but since the sensor does not send lines I need to redo my TCPClient class. I think that I could implement this code.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = socket.getInputStream().read(buffer)) != -1) {
result.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
// StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() > JDK 7
return result.toString("UTF-8");
```

To get the JSON data into a string, then I would have to parse it but that is for later.

My old code looks like this, does anyone have an idea how I could remake my old code to implement above method or a similar method so I can read the JSON data and turn it into a string so I can parse it later?

TcpClient

```
public class TcpClient {

....

/**
 * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
 */
public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;

}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 *
 * @param message text entered by client
 */

/**
 * Close the connection and release the members
 */
public void stopClient() {

    mRun = false;

    mMessageListener = null;
    mBufferIn = null;
    mServerMessage = null;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

        try {


            //receives the message which the server sends back
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {

                mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                }

            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }

}

//Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
//class at on asynckTask doInBackground
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}

}
```

My AsyncClass in other activity

```
  public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

    @Override
    protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object
        mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        CO2 = values[0];
        //response received from server
        Log.d("CO2", values[0]);
        //process server response here....

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to deal with such case is to send the entire data at once.

This is possible by first sending the data size and then the data content like this:

```
outputStream.writeInt(message.length); 
outputStream.write(message);
```

and when reading the message, parse the length and then read the entire message like this:

```
int len = socketDataInputStream.readInt();                    
byte[] message = new byte[len];
socketDataInputStream.readFully(message, 0, message.length);
```

Hope this helps, goodluck.

Comment: When you say "sending the data size", do you mean from the sensor? since I do not have access to program the sensor. Sorry if I missunderstod you.

Comment: Do you have any experience if it is normal that data is sent from a server that ends without a linebreak? Should I contact the company that made the sensor? Or is there a solution to read the data and get every new data in a seperate string?

Comment: Seems I misunderstood you, do you only need to convert the JSON message to a string and parse it later? "com.google.code.gson" can easily do that. Include it in your app gradle as "compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'".

Comment: If the data sent from the server ends without a line break thats because the sender doesn't close the socket every time after sending. A workaround can be to check if the sent data is less than your buffer then consider it the end of the message.